# How to create plist and use dependent UIPickerView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

how to create plist and use dependent UIPickerView?  What code used to load ? Doing to me with only two columns but not with three.

```
CARS :
    Ford
        -fiesta
        -mondeo
        -kuga
     Audi:
        -A4
        -A6
MOTORBIKE
         /Yamaha:
               -xt 600
               -xt 125
```

Comment: "cars ford fiesta mondeo kuga audi A4 A6 motorbike yamaha xt 600 xt 125" - ***What???***

Comment: What? You really need to clarify this question.

Comment: Guys, I think he wants this kind of picker :http://i45.tinypic.com/2ut565s.png . When Category CAR is selected, he wants car models in right handside.

Comment: We just need to create a plist where cars have a car brand and type of car

Comment: How many components do you want? From what I could make out. You want to have three components, first one cars/motorbikes. second one manufactures of cars/motorbike, third one models for each selected car/bike. Do clarify.

Comment: I have worked out a sample, check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This structure has a three level hierarchy. For simplicity i have considered an array with dictionary structure for plist.

[image]

Each node will have uniqueId, Name and SubItems. SubItems will have its own children and this will repeat for three levels. Considering this would be easier.

For displaying such a structure there should be one root collection with all the data. For each selection made in each component a selectedNode is cached, which would be used to find the subNodes.

I have worked out a [demo project](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35012982/Demo%20Projects/DemoMultiPickerView.zip) for this. It would be easier to know by code.

Comment: @Teoo333 Glad to help you, now that question is closed you can atleast give an upvote :)